# How do I have a persistent file storage when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, paperclip, persistent-storage

I know that Heroku's dyno gets refreshed each time a deploy is made so is there anyway I can have my files persistent or there's no other way but use services like amazon S3? I use paperclip to handle file upload and most of the files will be in pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use S3 or another service.

> #### Ephemeral filesystem
>
> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with
>   a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s
>   lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary
>   scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in
>   any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the
>   dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno
>   is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day
>   as part of normal dyno management.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: can paperclip be used with any free services? like dropbox...etc. My project it's pretty small and I my current need is just some simple storage. Thank you.

Comment: You can store the PDF's as a binary if they are not too big.