# Why does Heroku not save changes that my code writes to a file?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

If I run my code on my machine, the changes I write to the file using my code when it's incrementing the number inside `count.txt` by one are successfully written to `count.txt`. But, when my app is running on heroku, the changes to the file are neither made or saved. I opened terminal, did bash, `cat count.txt`, and read the contents of `count.txt` while users in my server were using the bot: there were no changes to the file. The number I manually put into the file is still there, unaltered. Is there a reason why this happens, and is there a solution?

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import re


class Counting(commands.Cog):
    """ Users take turns incrementing a number. """

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.count_channel = 761981805862846525
        self.num_regex = re.compile(r'(^\d+)')
        self.cum_num = None
        self.filename = "count.txt"

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            read_data = f.read()
            self.cum_num = int(read_data)

        if message.channel.id == self.count_channel:
            try:
                match_obj = self.num_regex.search(message.content)
                if int(match_obj.group(1)) != self.cum_num + 1:
                    await message.author.send(f'Your message must start with **{self.cum_num + 1}**!')
                    await message.delete()
                else:
                    self.cum_num += 1
                    with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
                        f.write(str(self.cum_num))
            except AttributeError:
                if message.author.id != self.client.user.id:
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.author.send(f"Your message must be a number!")```
````

Comment: Heroku dynos do not have persistent filesystems, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091667/how-do-i-have-a-persistent-file-storage-when-deploying-to-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not support such things. Use an online database instead. (I am using [MongoDB](https://cloud.mongodb.com) for example).

Good luck!